# jQuery .find() does not work on async elements loaded via Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, find

I'm using Angular to include a template in my html with ng-include and I'm using jQuery .find() to do some stuff, like this:

`$('.selector').find('.myClass').each(function(){
   // do stuff
})`

It seems that the elements with class 'myClass' included in the template are not seen at all by jQuery .find().

Is there any way to do achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Where are you doing this? in an Angular controller?

Comment: Nope, in an external jQuery file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is -- DOM rendering. You need to do something like that:

```
$timeout(function () {
    angular.element('.selector').find('.myClass').each(function(){
       // do stuff
    })
})
```

If it's external jQ file then try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.selector').find('.myClass').each(function(){
       // do stuff
    })
}, 0)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much @Max, this solution works like a charm :) You can vote for my question if you want.

Answer (score -1):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint.

Assuming, your code example is inside an Angular controller or directive, you are not dealing with the "normal" jQuery. In order to use all jQuery functions, include jQuery before angular.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianS but I cannot use jqLite instead of jQuery because I'm using some plugins depending on it.

Comment: It's absolutely different! The problem is asyncronisation